# How to find last index of item in linked list in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I just started a data structures and algorithms class and was introduced to linked lists for the first time.
I have a decent understanding of how they work in theory but am having a hard time working with them.

I am struggling with this homework assignment:

Write a method lastIndexOf that accepts an integer value as a parameter and that returns the index in the list of the last occurrence of that value, or -1 if the value is not found in the list. For example, if a variable list stores the following sequence of values, then the call of list.lastIndexOf(18) should return 6 because that is the index of the last occurrence of 18:

[1, 18, 2, 7, 18, 39, 18, 40]
If the call had instead been list.lastIndexOf(3), the method would return -1 because 3 does not appear in the list. You may not call any other methods of the class to solve this problem.

Assume that you are adding this method to the LinkedIntList class as defined below:

```
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;   // null for an empty list
    ...
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public int lastIndexOf(int value) {
    ListNode current = front;
    int target;
    while (current != null) {
      
    if(current.data == value) {
        target = current.data;
         return target;
    }
      current = current.next;
     
        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now the 2 issues I am facing are 1) that I am returning the actual value of the node and not its index, and 2) that I am only returning the first occurrence of that value and not the last.

I hope this isn't a stupid question and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You have a loop that iterates over the list until it finds the end. Now you need something that counts. Just use a variable and increment it on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `target` to `-1` and return `target` after the loop; if the `value` is found update `target` to the current index. Obviously, `target` will thus be the last match after the loop (or `-1` if there were no matches). You could use a `for` loop and `i` to keep the index. Something like,

```
public int lastIndexOf(int value) {
    ListNode current = front;
    int target = -1;
    for (int i = 0; current != null; i++) {
        if (current.data == value) {
            target = i;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution definitely works but I am a little confused about how it works. Specifically the current != null; part is confusing to me.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `while (current != null) {` except it adds `i` and increments it on every iteration of the loop. `int i = 0; while (current != null) { /* ... */ current = current.next; i++; }` would do the same.